# Submit form (without runat=server) from aspx page

Tags: asp.net, webforms

as we all know there is only one form possible on aspx page. How can I add html form to aspx page from code begind and submit data of this created form?
Here is form example:

```
<form name="payment" method="post" action="https://sci.interkassa.com/" accept-charset="UTF-8"> 
<input type="hidden" name="ik_co_id" value="51237daa8f2a2d8413000000" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="ik_pm_no" value="ID_4233" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="ik_am" value="1.44" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="ik_desc" value="Payment Description" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Pay"> 
</form>
```

I have and idea to build string using ClientScriptManager first and than attach this form to div using jQuery. Something like that. Is there some bettre ideas?

I'm going to use something like that, but I don't like this solution:

```
Dim sname As [String] = "Interkassa"
            Dim stype As Type = Me.[GetType]()
            Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
            If Not cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(stype, sname) Then
                Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
                sb.Append("<script type=text/javascript>")
                sb.Append("$(document).ready(function () { var s = ""<form name='payment' method='post' action='https://sci.interkassa.com/' accept-charset='UTF-8'><input type='submit' value='Оплата через Интеркассу'></form>"";")
                sb.Append("html = $.parseHTML(s);$('#interkassa').append(html);});")
                sb.Append("</script>")
                cs.RegisterStartupScript(stype, sname, sb.ToString())
            End If
```

Comment: Why are you using Web Forms but not using the Controls that come with Web Forms? Why do you want to add this HTML from code behind instead of declaring it on the ASPX page and then selectively showing it when necessary?

Comment: I'd like to create this form from code behind because I need to use some data from code.

Comment: Embed a `<IFrame>` on top of it and treat it as separate page

Comment: Along the same lines as @msm8bball - are you just looking for a way out of the default postback behavior in Webforms? See [PostBackUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Guys, sorry for the delay, but all my attention took by my newborn daughter. I will try both solutions and let you know.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, but final solution was completeky different - I did created new page beacause anyway I need page for success and fail action.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the HTML using code behind. That's a bad practice because it provides poor separation between logic and markup. Instead, create a button on your page where it fires a server side event, then have your server side event handle the logic.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="MyPaymentPanel">
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitPaymentBtn" Text="Pay" OnClick="SubmitPaymentBtn_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Then in your code behind...

```
protected void SubmitPaymentBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Retrieve values for ik_co_id, ik_pm_no etc from your database
//post the form if sending to a site you don't control, or update your database if you control sci.interkassa.com
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<button id="ClearButton" class="Button2" onclick="javascript:temp();return false;">CLEAR</button>

<script type=text/javascript>
Function temp
{
  // your code
}
</script>
```

Comment: How does this add an html form element to the page ?